# HTML: on hyperlink click nav container blinks

Tags: html, css, href, blink, onmousedown

whats up.

I am trying to code fixed navigation that stays at the top of the page all the time and I am dealing with the problem that my fixed navigation blinks every time when a `href` got clicked. Any ideas how to fix that?

HTML:

```
<nav id='nav_bar' >
<div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-md-3"><div class="miniLogo"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="footerContainerActive" align="center">
        <div class="footerLinksContainer"><a href="#" onclick="to_position('.apiemusJump')">Apie mus</a></div>
        <div class="footerLinksSkirtukas"></div>
        <div class="footerLinksContainer"><a href="#" onmousedown ="to_position('.paslaugosJump')">Paslaugos</a></div>
        <div class="footerLinksSkirtukas"></div>
        <div class="footerLinksContainer"><a href="#" onclick="to_position('.galerijaJump')">Galerija</a></div>
        <div class="footerLinksSkirtukas"></div>
        <div class="footerLinksContainer">Kontaktai</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Javascript:
https://pastebin.com/wssgU5ZY

CSS:
https://pastebin.com/7nV9aHT1

Comment: please provide `javascript` and `css` code as well

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to paste all the **relevant** code here to create a [MCVE]. Please take some time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Edited. There are some links now

Answer (score -1):

Include this in your CSS File.

```
.a:hover,.a:active,.a:focus
  {
  text-decoration:none;
  }
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Okey guys, now I checked it with Firefox browser and it was all good. Is it all about chrome?